# In split-tunneling, how do I configure OpenVPN so that it uses domain instead of IP based routing rules?

Tags: networking, vpn, routing, openvpn, domain

I live in a place where Google/Facebook/Twitter and a few other websites are not available from accessing. OpenVPN is a great tool to overcome this.

Originally, I must have OpenVPN running all the time in order to be able to have an uninterruptible access to the above listed sites, but the problem is that having all my traffic go through VPN, some websites(local to my country) would be too slow. Later on, I learned that split tunneling could be utilized so that only specific websites go through the VPN, and all other traffic would go through the local network.

However, until now, I am only able to do this using IP address as follows:

```
route-nopull
route 1.2.3.4
```

I'd have to specify hosts entries to map ip address to hostnames. But the problem is, sites like google and facebook have quite a lot of IP addresses, and each of which could be used for only a specific sub-domain. This is a lot of work and hard to maintain.

From Googling, people seem to be talking about `allow-pull-fqdn`, which seems to be used for retrieving IP addresses from the server using the FQDN, and config is like the following:

```
allow-pull-fqdn
route-nopull
route google.com
```

in which, the ip address of google.com would be retrieved from the OpenVPN server, so that I wouldn't have to specify it locally. But so far I haven't been able to make it work, which makes me wonder if it could be used in my case after all.

The documentation on OpenVPN is not so detailed, and I haven't been able to find more information about this elsewhere, could you please point me to the right direction?

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Routing works on IP addresses. It is not at all concerned with DNS names. What you want can simply not be done. You need to go higher (a proxy for example) in the protocol stack, where host names are meaningful.

Comment: @DanielB yes I understand routing happens on network layer, what I wan to know is that if there’s mechanism in OpenVPN which could translate domain name to IP address before the routing actually happens

Comment: OpenVPN is not concerned with the routing process. It receives packages only after the routing decision has been made.

Comment: It's a lot easier to make a network namespace with OpenVPN instead of using split tunneling. Start a browser in that namespace for all your VPN pages, start a second browser in the main namespace for all your country's websites.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try using a netmask for the website you are looking to acess?
as described [here](https://www.comparitech.com/blog/vpn-privacy/vpn-split-tuenneling/)

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: https://forums.openvpn.net/viewtopic.php?t=8229